# "Wake up me" or "Wake me up" ? "Switch off the lights" or "Switch the lights off"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, prepositional-phrases

I wonder about "prepositional verbs" that comes with Object :

> Wake me up.

or

> Wake up me.

---

> Switch the lights off.

or

> Switch off the lights

where should we place the preposition ? after the verb or the object ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With true phrasal verbs like *switch off* and *wake up*, where the object falls depends on the 'weight' of the object. A 'heavy' object (one with many words) falls after the preposition/particle.<sup>†</sup>.

> I switched off [the lights in the upstairs hallway, bedrooms, and staircase].
>   I woke up [those of my exhausted fellows who had collapsed where they stood].

Putting the preposition/particle after such an object strands it too far from the verb, so both readers and hearers have to grope for the structure.

A medium-weight object may come before or after the preposition/particle.

> I switched the overhead lights off. *OR* I switched off the overhead lights.
>   I woke John and Ryan up. *OR*  I woke up John and Ryan.

But a very light object, like a single preposition, always comes before the preposition/particle.

> I switched it off. *BUT NOT* *I switched off it.
>   I woke him up.  *BUT NOT* *I woke up him.

---

<sup>†</sup>What you call *off* and *up* here varies among grammarians.

Comment: I'd say the "very light" objects are only pronouns (you wrote "prepositions", you might want to edit that). For example, a sentence like "Time to wake up Mo." sounds fine to me, and Mo is a proper name.

Answer (score 0):

These are called as *adverbial particles*. They have special privilege to fit **between the verb and the object noun**. I had read it on Swan's PEU.

So, it is preferred this way...

> Switch off the light

Switch - verb
*off* - adverbial particle
*the* light - object noun.

Comment: To defend Swan's name, I'd like to know which entry of *Practical English Usage* that you refer to. As far as I can recall, Swan don't use the term *adverbial particles*. (He seems to prefer *adverb particles*. The closest entry I found is entry 20, where he wrote *"Small adverbs like these are usually called 'adverb(ial) particles'."* The bigger surprise for me is the term *subject noun*, which I'm rather sure that he doesn't call it so. I also couldn't find the term *subject noun* mentioned, not even once, in his book. Do you use a different edition of the book I have?

Comment: Ah, did I write 'subject'.... it's 'object noun'. Sorry for that terrible mistake. And yes, it's in entry 20.1. The version is fully revised third version.